# Find similar values in two different columns, within error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in PostgreSQL from where I would like to query one column based on the other one.
The two columns are filled with numbers (float) and I would like to select the ones that are close to each other within an error of +- 1
Have anyone encountered a similar problem? How did you solved it?
Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to be sure that your problem is 100% clear.  What if there are no matches in the range?  What if there are multiple matches?  What if there is a tie for the best?

Answer (score 0):

Use `between` whose range is the reference number ±1:

```
select * from my_table
where my_column between some_number - 1 and some_number + 1
```

Comment: Thank you Bohemian! This would return the values between the values I set, however I would like to compare two different columns and return the row where they match. For example: my fist column contains numbers and the second one as well. I would like to return the row where my values from table 1 and 2 are close, within the set range

Comment: @user16584190 are there more than 1 rows that could match? If so, do you want the closest one or all of them?

Comment: Yes, there are more rows that could match and I would like the closest one!